# Make user's name display as the site name in comments if it matches certain roles | wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

So here's what I'm trying to do. I'm working on a plugin and I want to check each comment and see if the author of that comment has a role of "administrator" or "editor". If they do, rather than display their user name and avatar, I would like to display the name of the website along with a company logo or something. I'm pretty new to WordPress development and am stuck on this. I can't figure out if there is a filter for this, or if I need to create a custom comments template. If someone could even just get me pointed in the right direction that would be great, because at this point, i'm not even sure where I should start. Thank you.

Where I am, My thought process:

```
<?php 
function anonymize_author(){
    global $post;

    //get the id of the comment author
    $author_id = $post->post_author;

    //get the userdata of comment author
    $author_info = get_userdata($author_id);

    //get the user roles of comment author
    $author_roles = $author_info->roles;

    //Array of roles to check against
    $roles_to_check = ["editor", "administrator"];

    //see if user has a role in my $roles_to_check array
    $results = array_intersect($roles_to_check, $author_roles);

    if(!empty($results)){
        //the user has roles of either "editor" or "administrator"
        //load custom comments page?
        //I need to display the author name as the site name
        //and the avatar as the site logo
    }else{
        //Just a regular user, load the Wordpress Default comments
    }
}

add_filter('some_filter_here', 'anonymize_author');
```

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the comments, check to see if comment name is "admin", something like this:

```
// check to see if the comment author name is admin
if ( "admin" == get_comment_author() ) {
   // your condition
}
```

for this to work, when commenting as site administrator, you should use the name `admin`. You can also use `get_comment_author_email()` to match for admin email:

```
    $all_users = get_users(); // get all users
    // loop through all users
    foreach ($all_users as $user) {
        // if the user email matches the commenter's email
        // and user has admin role
        if ( $user->user_email == get_comment_author_email() && in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ))
        {
            // your condition
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Dolatabadi, thanks for responding. I have to check the roles, the user names will change and others will be added. I have 2 different roles I need to check for: "editor", "administrator". Also, where would I hook in? Would I use a filter?

Answer (score 0):

Using a [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) was the way to go. I found two hooks that fit my need:
[get_comment_author_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_comment_author_link/) and [get_avatar_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_avatar_url/).
Here is how I applied them to my problem:

```
//plugin.php

/*
 * A function that compares users roles
 */
function check_user_roles($user_roles){
    //array of roles to check
    $roles_to_check = ["editor", "administrator"];

    //see if user roles match any $roles_to_check values
    $results = array_intersect($roles_to_check, (array) $user_roles);

    if(!empty($results)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }           
}

/*
 * Callback function for the get_comment_author_link filter
 */
function anonymize_author($return, $author, $comment_id){
    //find comment data
    $comment_data = get_comment($comment_id);

    //find authors user_id
    $user_id = $comment_data->user_id;

    //check that author is a registered user before proceeding
    if($user_id > 0){
        //get user data
        $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

        //get users roles
        $user_roles = $user->roles;

        if(check_user_roles($user_roles)){
            $author = bloginfo('name');
        }
    }
    return $author;
}

/*
 * Callback function for the get_avatar_url filter
 */
function anonymizer_avatar($url, $id_or_email, $args){
    $user = false;
    if(is_numeric($id_or_email)){
        $id = (int) $id_or_email;
        $user = get_user_by('id', $id);
    }elseif(is_object($id_or_email)){
        if(!empty($id_or_email->user_id)){
            $id = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
            $user = get_user_by('id', $id);
        }
    }else{
        $user = get_user_by('email', $id_or_email);
    }

    if($user && is_object($user)){
        $user_roles = $user->roles;
        if(check_user_roles($user_roles)){
            $url = "URL_TO_MY_IMAGE";
        }
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter('get_avatar_url', 'anonymize_avatar', 1, 3);
add_filter('get_comment_author_link', 'anonymize_author', 1, 3);
```